# Why do the first few clicks do not work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, onclick, click

My webapp uses jQuery along with jQueryUI components.
The events are attached using the following scheme:

```
$(function(){
    ...
    $('#id').click(function(){...});
    // and
    $(document).on('click', '.dynamic-element', function(){});
    ...
});
```

If I click a button on the page, it happens sometimes that the first few clicks not trigger the click action, although the button "pushes in".

The weirdest thing is that I only observe this in Chrome 32, not Firefox 27 nor Safari 6 (I use a Mac).  I've got real frustrated with this. The console does not give any errors.

What could be the problem? Is there any workaround?

**Update**

I have tried this (within a $(document).ready of course):

```
$('#share').click(function(){
    console.log('share clicked');
    // ... further code ...
});
```

after 20 page refreshes, I've got a completely non-registered click. :S
Here we go. :)

**Update 2:**

Here comes the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22P2D/
Open console, open page in two tabs, and you have a fair chance it produces the phenomenon. As it did not to me.

Comment: Can u reproduce the problem in fiddle ?

Comment: @Halim Qarroum `$(function(){` is equal to `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Which handler are you talking about '#id' click or delegated one??? What are these handlers? You just have posted empty functions, maybe your issue is related to these handlers, not binding events. Could be quite easy to check this

Comment: @A.Wolff Both and it does happen randomly... now I added ;"use strict"; to the top of each file and I can't reproduce the problem. *(nope, I've got it again, just around 10 refreshes needed :D)

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Well `"use strict"` is not supposed to fix this behaviour or at least i don't see why it should

Comment: @ Barnabas Szabolcs, is it possible that the click event does execute, but the function code simply fails? did you try putting an alert first thing in the function to see if it executes?

Comment: Could it be that you're pressing the button **before** the page finishes loading? Your event handlers won't be attached until the DOM is ready.

Comment: @ Oscar Paz shouldnt you read the other comments before asking answered questions

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs You should try upgrading to chrome 33 and see what's going on. You should by the way try to replicate issue on other computer, with different OS, etc...

Comment: @TusharGupta I'll try, although this problem seems to appear once you have a nice elaborated app.

Comment: @A.Wolff I could replicate it on a different MBP, with Chrome, but I don't know its version.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Bugs always appear when they shouldn't... ;)

Comment: So it could be related to your code. It would be nice if you could provide any online link which replicates your issue so we could test it